# Why does this pattern not produce an error?

Tags: pcre2

Compiled PCRE2 10.39 from source on aarch64 (Apple M1). If I use the pattern `Product\d{2,}` it compiles and matches correctly, but if I instead use the pattern `Product\d{2` it doesn't produce any compile error (`pcre2_compile`) but rather just doesn't match anything when calling `pcre2_match`. Is this by design? Can it be configured to produce an error instead?

Comment: Don't it then just matches literal `{`? https://regex101.com/r/PwG9he/1 Try regex e.g. `Product\d{12312312342342342}`

Comment: @Justinas : yes it does, but isn't that a problematic fallback mechanism, making it hard to find erroneous patterns? If I wanted to match the literal `{` I should be forced to use `\{` as with other special characters.

Comment: If there is no matching closing `}` then it's literal string.

Answer (score 0):

In line with @Justinas' comments, I found the answer in the PCRE2 Spec https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC17 :

> An opening curly bracket that appears in a position where a quantifier is not allowed, or one that does not match the syntax of a quantifier, is taken as a literal character. For example, {,6} is not a quantifier, but a literal string of four characters.